# Uncaught TypeError without ability to find the reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Every time I right-click anywhere in my Application, jQuery is going to throw an error at line 5095 saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

To find the cause of this error I tried two ways without success:

**1. Debug jQuery:**

In the Dev-Tool's I debug jQuery at Line 5095. The Problem: When I move the cursor over the page, it will stop and break. I have NO possibility to get it to make a right click. Even if I press play in Chrome's Debug-Line which appears, it will instantly fire again, even if I won't move the cursor!

**2. Searching the reason in my code:**

Since this Error is thrown for a long time now I cannot tell where to search. I have multiple js-files. So I realized the error is being thrown when I release the mouse-button. So I searched ALL my code for ANY mouse(-up/down)-events without success (found several that wont fire if I set breakpoints)

Now I am out of ideas how to find the source of it. I thought debugging the line of jQuery where the error is thrown would give me access to the stack variables with possibly more information about its source. Any suggestions?

Please don't ask me to post code. Since I can't tell where the mistakes happen I might post thousands of lines of JavaScript. I need a logical way to find the Errorsource.

Comment: Do you have your code on a server somewhere you could link to?

Comment: Sorry this would not help you. I am sure. Its too many code. I need some logical approach (assistance) for this. My main problem is jQuery being debugged when i put the cursor on the webpage which takes me the ability of right-clicking the page, since the Error is only thrown on a page-right click (anywhere)

Comment: Well I suggest commenting out code until the error goes away. You can narrow down the suspects that way then start digging in

Comment: why dont you paste your code here and let us help u to troubleshoot it? this definitely is your script problem, you know how to open debugging tools? If yes, should can easily to find roughly where the error came from

Comment: Se0ng11 please read my question not just the title! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error definitely isn't in jquery or jquery-ui files. it's most definitely in a plugin's code or your custom code.

think of where the error might be. just do a basic estimation. and put a `console.log()` before those lines and run it again. see if the error occurs before the console output. if it happens before, investigate the code that executes before this line and the javascript files that are included before this file. if it happens after do the opposite. You can narrow down by putting multiple `console.log()s`

Comment: Sure this is not a jQuery bug. I searched ALL mouseevent binds in my code and put a console.log in the first line beside setting breakpoints. None of them were fired. This is why I get stuck so hard.

Comment: you say the error is being thrown when you release the mouse-button. that would happen with a `click()` are you sure any of your click event listeners isn't causing the error?

Comment: Forgot to say: ONLY on right-click release the error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

you can look at events with

```
$._data(element, "events")
```

but you cant see where the bind is in your code

maybe someone knows